# If a motherboard support 4GB DDR3 module, does it mean it can support 8GB modules?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What limits a motherboard from supporting more memory?](https://superuser.com/questions/308310/what-limits-a-motherboard-from-supporting-more-memory)

I have noticed, that 8Gb RAM modules finally appeared in the desktop market.
Also most of the new motherboards specs state that the maximum of 32Gb is supported and so 8Gb modules too. However, even 1-year old motherboard had only 4Gb modules specified in the manual.

So my question is: **does the upper limit for module size exists?** (e.g. does old MBs support 8GB modules, whenonly one such module is used, so **the max memory constraint isn't violated**)
If it is, what's the reason for it, especcially, when both MBs use the same north/south bridge?

In particular, I have an interest in [this MB](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_AM3/M4A89GTD_PRO/#specifications). I know that [MSI MB](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/890GXM-G65.html#?div=Detail) with the same chipset support 8Gb modules.

*P.S.
Modified version of a previous question. I just wanted to edit it, but it was closed (((
Hopefully this one won't be, cause I haven't find question about modules only.*

Comment: I've read this question. There is no answer about separate modules, only about total memory amount.

Comment: Please don't create a new question. Edit your existing one and flag it for a moderator to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Motherboards with the same chipset tend to support the same size RAM sticks, but that's not a rule and is commented in the linked ticket.

The upper limit for module size exists. It could be that your MB supports 8gb sticks off the shelf even if the manual says otherwise. Or maybe you only need a BIOS update to get it working.

Comment: And what is the reason for the upper limit? I've read that it partly depends on a number of chips on the module. So from two modules of equal sizes one (with a larger number of chips and so smaller chip size) can work and another - won't. Mb there are some other limitations?