# What is that define a motherboard RAM maximum?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I need to replace the motherboard of my laptop. I found one that should be perfect but it only support 1GB RAM while my old one support up to 8GB.

I was wondering, is there a chance I can upgrade the RAM limits replacing some parts from the old motherboard to the new one? Do you which parts are actually the ones who define this limits?

Answer (score 0):

You can see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/308315/368970) for a more detailed explanation of what exactly limits the RAM.

But the answer to your question is simple. There is no normal way to upgrade things on a motherboard. A motherboard is bought and used and isn't meant to be upgradable in itself.